# React/Axios - Display part of URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I'm using this [Dogs API](https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all) and want to display the name of the dog with the image generated.

Currently, the text when I click a button to generate a random image with the appropriate link to the image shows up like this:

`https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/basenji/n02110806_4280.jpg`

I want just the `basenji`, not the whole URL.

This can be shown in the `setText` function.

How can I just get the name of the dog from the URL and not the whole thing itself.

**CODE**

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {

  const [images, setImage] = React.useState("");
  const [text, setText]    = React.useState("");

  function btnClick() {

    axios
        .all([axios.get("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random"), 
              axios.get("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all")
         ]) 
        .then(axios.spread((response) => {
              setImage(response.data.message);
              setText(response.data.message);
         }))     
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("Error happened during fetching!", err);
        });
  }

  return (
    <div className = "App">
      <img    className = "Img" src={images} alt="broken"/>
      <button className = "Button" onClick = {btnClick}>Doggie!</button>
      <p>You got a {text}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although, dont know but if every link shows up the text like one you mentioned, the one of the solution would be to split the text on '/' based on index to get the breed

```
 .then(axios.spread((response) => {
              setImage(response.data.message);
              setText(response.data.message.split('/')[4]);
         }))
```

Comment: Nice, that solved it, will accept answer when I can, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex to capture the breed part of the path. `exec` returns an array with the match as the first element and all captured groups following.

```js
const breedRegex = /breeds\/(\w+)\//i;

const path = "https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/basenji/n02110806_4280.jpg";

console.log(breedRegex.exec(path));
```